# Hacer mas condicionales sin que entren en conflicto (if/else)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, json

Tengo que buscar dos valores que estan dentro de un json a traves de la información que coloque dentro de dos inputs, las condiciones que quiero que se cumplan, son cuatro, la primera es que si los dos campos estan vacios, pues me carge todo el json, cosa que hago bien, la segunda es que si el campo nombre esta relleno, cargo solamente los datos de dicho campo, cosa que también he conseguido. Sin embargo, no logro saber como colocar el resto de condiciones sin que entren en conflicto con los otros if/else. Las otras condiciones es que si el campo ID esta relleno, pues debo sacarlo el json, hasta el numero indicado, la condición la tengo, es esta :

```
else {
            $.each(resultado, function(i, valorJson) {
                if(i < $("#indentificador").val()){ //Si en el campo input hay un valor, mostrará una tabla con los valores menores a ese valor de i
                    tabla.append("<tr><td id='idPokemon'>" + valorJson.id + "</td>" + "<td id='nombrePokemon'>" + valorJson.name.english + "</td>" + "<td id='tiposPokemon'>" + valorJson.type + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button>" + "</td></tr>");}
            });
        }
```

Con ese condicional, averiguo que numero ha colocado el usuario y lo lee hasta el indicado, si pone un 12, pues me saca hasta el 12. El ultimo condicional que tendria que colocar seria el de Si ambos campos estan rellenos, pues que no se le haga caso al del ID y solo saque el del nombre. Adjunto mi codigo html y JS(el json no lo adjunto debido a su gran tamaño y que no es tan necesario mostrarlo)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#boton-json").on("click", function () { //Funcion pulsar botón carga archivo JSON
        $.ajax({
            url: "pokedex.json",
            success: function (resultado) { //Se carga el archivo JSON
                var tabla = $("<table class='table table-dark'>" //Creación de la tabla que contiene Id, Nombre, Tipo y Seleccion
                    +
                    "<tr><th><h2>Id</h2></th>" +
                    "<th><h2>Nombre</h2></th>" +
                    "<th><h2>Tipos</h2></th>" +
                    "<th><h2>Opciones</h2></th></tr>");

                
                //MOSTRAR TODOS LOS POKEMONS
                if (($("#identificador").val() === "") && ($("#pokemon").val() === "")) { //Si en el campo input no hay valores
                    $.each(resultado, function (i, objetoJSON) { //Por cada valor del archivo JSON
                        //Utilizamos append para implemenntar una tabla con los valores id, nombre, tipo
                        tabla.append("<tr><td id='idPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.id + "</td>" + "<td id='nombrePokemon'>" + objetoJSON.name.english + "</td>" + "<td id='tiposPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.type + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button>" + "</td></tr>");
                    });
                }
                //MOSTRAR POKEMON INDICADO SEGÚN EL NOMBRE
                else{ //Si en el campo input no hay valores
                    $.each(resultado, function (i, objetoJSON) {
                        if( ( $( "#identificador" ).val() == "" ) && ( $("#pokemon").val() == objetoJSON.name.english ) )  //Por cada valor del archivo JSON
                        //Utilizamos append para implemenntar una tabla con los valores id, nombre, tipo
                        tabla.append("<tr><td id='idPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.id + "</td>" + "<td id='nombrePokemon'>" + objetoJSON.name.english + "</td>" + "<td id='tiposPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.type + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button>" + "</td></tr>");
                    });
                } 

                $("#contenedor").html(tabla); //Se agrega en el div contenedor del html la tabla generada

                $(".seleccionar").on('click', function () { //Se configura el botón Seleccionar para que guarde el id y el nombre del pokemon
                    $.post("archivo.php", { //Por post se envia los datos al archivo PHP
                        op: 1,
                        idPokemon: $(this).closest("tr").find("#idPokemon").text(),
                        nombrePokemon: $(this).closest("tr").find("#nombrePokemon").text()
                    }, function (datos) {
                        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = datos;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

$("#boton-mostrar").on('click', function () { //funcion mostrar contenido del contenedor
    $.post("archivo.php", {
        op: 2
    }, function (datos) {

        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = datos;

        $(".borrar").on('click', function () { //Función borrado de contenido en el contenedor
            $.post("archivo.php", {
                op: 3,
                idPokemon: $(this).closest("tr").find("#idPokemon").text()
            }, function (datos) {
                document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = datos;
            });
        });
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>POKEDEX - PRÁCTICA 3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="styles/img/icono-pagina.png" type="image/ico" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="portada" class="my-row ">
    <div class="container fluid padding-portada">
      <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <img src="styles/img/logopokemon.png" class="img-fluid aumento">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
              let myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
              myAudio.onplaying = function () {
                isPlaying = true;
              };
              myAudio.onpause = function () {
                isPlaying = false;
              };
            });
            let isPlaying = false;

            function togglePlay() {
              if (isPlaying) {
                myAudio.pause()
              } else {
                myAudio.play();
              }
            }
          </script>
          <audio id="myAudio" src="./styles/music/musica.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

          <a class="btn" role="button" onClick="togglePlay()">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35" height="35" fill="currentColor"
              class="bi bi-play-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path
                d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM6.79 5.093A.5.5 0 0 0 6 5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 0 .79.407l3.5-2.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.814l-3.5-2.5z" />
            </svg></a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
    <div class="container fluid padding-interfaz">
        <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                        d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                        fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                <label for="numero" class="texto">Introduce el ID:</label>
                <input type="number" id="identificador" name="identificador" placeholder="ID del Pokemon" min="1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                        d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                        fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                <label for="nombre" class="texto">Introduce el nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" id="pokemon" name="pokemon" placeholder="Nombre del Pokemon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <button id="boton-json">Cargar JSON</button>
                <button id="boton-mostrar">Mostrar seleccionados</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
  <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
    <div class="container fluid">
      <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <button onClick="window.location.reload();" class="mt-4">Refresh Page</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="zona-pokemon" class="my-row mt-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div id="contenedor" class="tabla">

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="practica.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: solo debes usar un or ejemplo:  `if( ( $( "#identificador" ).val() == objetoJSON.id) || ( $("#pokemon").val() == objetoJSON.name.english ) )`  con esto validas uno u otro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi

ejemplo:

```
$.each(resultado, function (i, objetoJSON) { //Por cada valor del archivo JSON
    
    if( ( $( "#identificador" ).val() == objetoJSON.id) || ( $("#pokemon").val() == objetoJSON.name.english ) ) {
        tabla.append( `<tr><td id='idPokemon'> ${objetoJSON.id} </td>
         <td id='nombrePokemon'> ${objetoJSON.name.english} </td><td id='tiposPokemon'>${objetoJSON.type} 
         </td> <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button></td></tr>`);
    }
    // si no coincide con ninguno de arriba es que ta vacio o mal escrito
    // y ejecutara todo 
    else if( ( $( "#identificador" ).val() == "") || ( $("#pokemon").val() == "" ) ){
           tabla.append( `<tr><td id='idPokemon'> ${objetoJSON.id} </td> 
            <td id='nombrePokemon'> ${objetoJSON.name.english}  
            </td><td id='tiposPokemon'> ${objetoJSON.type}
            </td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button></td></tr>`);
        }
        
});
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto!, me ha funcionado, muchas gracias.